# Error running Beam job with DataFlow runner (using Bazel): no module found error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, bazel, dataflow

I am trying to run a beam job on dataflow using the python sdk.

My directory structure is :

```
beamjobs/
  setup.py
  main.py
  beamjobs/
    pipeline.py
```

When I run the job directly using `python main.py`, the job launches correctly. I use `setup.py` to package my code and I provide it to beam with the runtime option `setup_file`.

However if I run the same job using bazel (with a `py_binary` rule that includes `setup.py` as a data dependency), I end up getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 804, in run
    work, execution_context, env=self.environment)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/workitem.py", line 131, in get_work_items
    work_item_proto.sourceOperationTask.split)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/workercustomsources.py", line 144, in __init__
    source_spec[names.SERIALIZED_SOURCE_KEY]['value'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 290, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 462, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beamjobs'
```

This is surprising to me because the logs show above:
`Successfully installed beamjobs-0.0.1 pyyaml-5.4.1`
So my package is installed successfully.

I don't understand this discrepancy between running with python or running with bazel.

In both cases, the logs seem to show that dataflow tries to use the image `gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/python37:2.29.0`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that I was sending the file `setup.py` as a dependency in bazel; and I could see in the logs that my package `beamjobs` was being installed correctly.

The issue is that the package was actually empty, because the only dependency I included in the `py_binary` rule was that `setup.py` file.
The fix was to also include all the other python files as part of the binary. I did that by creating `py_library` rules to add all those other files as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the wrapper-runner script generated by Bazel (you can find path to it by calling `bazel build` on a target) restrict set of modules available in your script. The proper approach is to fetch PyPI dependencies by Bazel, look at [example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/tree/master/examples/pip_install)

Comment: That's what I do, I provide `apache-beam` as a dependency using python_rules.
I see in the dataflow logs that both apache-beam and my package (from setup.py) are installed correctly